# How to show dropdown values with count using Angularjs Dropdown Multiselect?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, multi-select

[AngularJS Dropdown Multiselect](http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/docs/#/main) -- Search Custom template per option.

I have found the solution of my query will be using the above url of the documentation of AngularJS Dropdown Multiselect but if I am using the below code, it doesn't reflect on the view of my application:

```
$scope.example19settings = {
    template: '<b>{{option.name}}</b>'
};
```

I want to acheive it by adding a count:

```
$scope.example19settings = {
    template: '<b>{{option.name}}({{option.count}})</b>'
};
```

Any suggestions or missing links?

```
$scope.extraSettings = {
    settings: {
        selectedToTop: true,
        styleActive: true,
        /*template: '<b>{{option.label}}</b>'*/
        scrollable: true,
        scrollableHeight: 200,
        showEnableSearchButton: true        
    }
};
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/edisonpappi/pen/KymEpr see this sample

Comment: Thanks @Edison but i want the count in Alabama which is the option inside the dropdown in the example you have shown.. let me know if u want any clarity

Comment: see https://codepen.io/edisonpappi/pen/vWmqVd?editors=1010

Comment: Not sure this serves my purpose, cannot we achieve this using angularjs-dropdown-multiselect library?

Comment: @GOK if you could provide a working example of your code we would get a better chance at helping you, also, which version of the library are you using?

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi: I am using angular multiselect of this url : https://rawgit.com/billyaraujo/angular-dropdown-multiselect/master/dist/angular-dropdown-multiselect.js

Comment: @GOK Is this all you're talking about? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bYowZP

Answer (score 5):

Please find working solution below. Following are the changes I have done.

1. Change the reference if `miltiselect` library to [this](https://rawgit.com/dotansimha/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/master/dist/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect.min.js) (latest)
2. Added the `'angularjs-dropdown-multiselect'` as dependency to my main app module
3. Created a controller `MainCtrl`, assigned it to the template
4. Added an extra property (`$scope.example19model = [];`) to `$scope` for holding selected options.

Let me know, if this works for you :)

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['angularjs-dropdown-multiselect']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.example19model = [];
  $scope.example19data = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "David",
    count: 20
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: "Jhon",
    count: 30
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: "Lisa",
    count: 40
  }, {
    id: 4,
    name: "Nicole",
    count: 50
  }, {
    id: 5,
    name: "Danny",
    count: 60
  }];

  $scope.example19settings = {
    template: '<b>{{option.name}} ({{option.count}})</b>'
  };
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/dotansimha/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/master/dist/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="example19data" selected-model="example19model" extra-settings="example19settings"></div>
    {{example19model}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am if you misunderstood; i want to implement David with a count like David(20) and Jhon(30).

Comment: Where is count?

Comment: Please see modified answer, if that is what you mean.

Comment: @GOK Any luck??

Answer (score 1):

You can use [select2](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select) library which helps to select multiple inputs.

Check this [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) for live demo.

`<h3>Array of strings</h3>
  <ui-select multiple ng-model="ctrl.multipleDemo.colors" theme="bootstrap" ng-disabled="ctrl.disabled" close-on-select="false" style="width: 300px;" title="Choose a color">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select colors...">{{$item}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="color in ctrl.availableColors | filter:$select.search">
      {{color}}
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
  <p>Selected: {{ctrl.multipleDemo.colors}}</p>`