# How can we achieve product filter page using angularjs with multi selection of checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I have created a tabular page in which i need to filter the table with filters using a left side facets boxes of different category but with multi-selection options and i need to use Angularjs for this requirement.

I need to check/uncheck using the clear filter selection .

Any helping library can help to achieve the same or we need to do some logic around the checkboxes to achieve this.

My checkbox code looks like this:

```
 <div class="col-sm-2" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 20px;">
                <div class="facetBx sltBx" ng-show="tabFilters.length > 0">
                    <p class="facetBxTitle"><i class="fa fa-filter"></i>&nbsp;Filter Selection
                        <a class="clrSlt" ng-click="clearAllFilters();">Clear</a>
                    </p>

                    <div class="facetBxChld" id="uRslctn">

                        <ul>
                            <li ng-repeat="item in tabFilters">

                                <div class="crop">
                                    <strong title="{{item}}">{{item}}</strong>
                                </div>
                                <i class="fa fa-remove rmvThs" style="font-size: 14px;color:#000;float: right;" ng-click="checkItem(item, item,false);"></i>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="facetBx" ng-repeat="item in filters">
                    <p class="facetBxTitle bomtype">{{item.label}}</p>

                    <div class="facetBxChld" id="bomFacet">
                        <ul class="multiselect" style="max-height: 140px;overflow-y: auto;">
                            <li ng-repeat="(k,v) in item.values">
                                <input type="checkbox" ng-model='isSelected' ng-click='checkItem(item.name, k, isSelected)'>
                                <span> {{k}} ({{v}})</span>
                            </li>
                            <li ng-show="value.length == 0">
                                No Data Available.
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Below website are the reference of the code which i am trying to build:

www.jabong.com

The UI(HTML) is done but i am facing the trouble in the maintaining the checking and un-checking of the checkboxes which are not clearing off.

I believe i need to code something in the ng-model of checkbox to achieve it but i am not able to be successfull so need help on the same.

Sample Plunkur for the same:

[enter link description here](https://plnkr.co/edit/xVdTise2UYLsi7piJnbC?p=preview)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's better to response in case of bounty questions whether supplied answer works for your or not. On your last bounty question, you didn't show up at the time of awarding the bounty. Please keep that in mind for future questions. Ref (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47260040/how-to-show-dropdown-values-with-count-using-angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/47397215#47397215)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to keep track of `ng-model` of checkboxes with some property in your `$scope`. I did this by modifying your `$scope.filters` and adding `selected` property inside it, like below.

```
var filters = [{
  label: 'Brand',
  name: 'brand',
  values: {
    Blackberrys: 503,
    Arrow: 175,
    ParkAvenue: 358
  }
}, {
  label: 'Color',
  name: 'color',
  values: {
    Black: 100,
    Green: 200,
    Red: 300
  }
}]

function loadFilters() {
  $scope.filters = filters.map(function(filter) {
    var filter = angular.copy(filter);
    for (var key in filter.values) {
      filter.values[key] = {
        selected: false,
        count: filter.values[key]
      }
    }
    return filter;
  })
}

loadFilters();
```

Then you can call `loadFilters()` any time you want to clear all filters. Please see POC attached below.

https://plnkr.co/edit/SADPoUpftnJkg1rMuSB9?p=preview

Comment: Here you have shown to alter the main json to attah with props; we have diffrerent section to draw the filters;then again one more section to fill the items which are filtered. My issue is a different one, i am facing issue in clearing the checkbox from an external click which is a clear filter selection panel which has individual filters selected from the list. Not able to figure out how to get to the checkbox when cleared from external panel.

Comment: Please create a minimal fiddler/plunker link in that case. Because we are not sure what your structure will be.

Comment: what can't we modify main JSON? is there any restriction in it?

Comment: Check the plunkur, i am trying to maintain two scopes for filters and tabfilters which is to show a list of filters which are selected from below list. Now there is a close button(x); i need to additionally handle that which item's x is clicked so that i can clear the checkbox

Comment: Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Yes, please check here https://plnkr.co/edit/dvZ7cxnHGVnn0galEl7R?p=preview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160598/discussion-between-vipin-kumar-and-gok).

Comment: Great you did that.. i achieved it from different way

Answer (score 0):

You should try '**ng-change**' on checkboxes to trigger a method which changes the values according to checked and unchecked checkboxes.

For Ex.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model='isSelected' ng-click='checkItem(key, k, isSelected)' ng-change="yourMethodHere()">
```

in JS:

```
$scope.yourMethodHere = function() {
  if (isSelected) {
    // filter the values here
  } else {
    // non filtered values
  }
}
```

By doing this you do not need to even maintain the values of exiting checked/unchecked checkbox.

Comment: Do you have a small POC to show this, didn't get the context of it.